# setup.py find_packages() not installing packages to anaconda environment

Tags: python, setuptools

if I run my `setup.py` file with `python setup.py install` from the anaconda enviroment env it does not install the packages.

Folder structure:

```
|setup.py
|package_name/
|---__init__.py
|---package_one.py
|---package_two.py
```

`setup.py`content:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='NAME',
    version='1.0',
    description="libraries",
    license="MIT",
    packages=find_packages(),
    author="Max",
    scripts={},
)
```

The package files contain each a class e.g.
`package_one.py`

```
class class_one():
    def __init__(self, root_path, project_path):
        self.root_path = root_path
        self.project_path = project_path
        self.project = Project()
        self.hostname = os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']
```

after running setup.py I can't import any package with `from package_name.package_one import class_one` what am I missing?

Comment: Did you resolve this @MadMax?

Answer (score 0):

> I cant import any package with from package_name.package_one import class_one

This will only work if your current working directory is root folder of the project, in this case the parent folder which contains `/package_name`. Otherwise, it will give `ModuleNotFoundError`.

You can try the approach below. This specifies which packages to include, but also the use of `package_name` separately includes the files in the base of the directory.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='NAME',
    version='1.0',
    description="libraries",
    license="MIT",
    packages=find_packages(include=['package_name', 'package_name.*']),
    author="Max",
    scripts={},
)
```

Read [this](https://godatadriven.com/blog/a-practical-guide-to-using-setup-py/) for more details.